# Fortran OOP Function Overloading

Tags: oop, fortran, overloading

I have two functions, one that splits a delimited string to an integer
array, and another to a real array. Which I am trying to overload.

```
Interface split
  Module Procedure split_to_int_unidim
  Module Procedure split_to_real_unidim
End Interface split

Function split_to_int_unidim (a, delim, pos) Result (b)
  Character(len=*), Intent (in) :: a, delim
  Character(len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: pos
  Integer, Allocatable :: b(:)
End Function

Function split_to_real_unidim (a, delim, pos) Result (b)
  Character(len=*), Intent (in) :: a, delim
  Character(len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: pos
  Real, Allocatable :: b(:)
End Function
```

I am getting the error

```
gfortran -o build/lib/foul.o -c -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib lib/foul.f
lib/foul.f:22.41:

Module Procedure split_to_real_unidim
                                     1
Error: Ambiguous interfaces 'split_to_real_unidim' and 'split_to_int_unidim' 
in generic interface 'split' at (1)
```

I was hoping that since the return of the functions are of different types, I would be ok.
However I seem to be mistaken looking at the error. Is there any way I can call them using the same name? If so, what modifications would I need to do?

Comment: Return types are not part of the function signature. Only arguments are of different types the compiler can distinguish between the two methods.

Comment: Possible typo: Shoudn't the second method be `split_to_real_unidim`

Comment: You are correct, typo has now been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with using these two functions is that by including
an additional variable to resolve ambiguation in the arguments, 
makes their use non-intuitive. The problem occurs because we want
to split the delimited string to an integer or real array without
having to remember to include a non-intuitive variable.

A good solution is to include the first output element b1 as an
output argument. This additional argument would be consistent when
use both functions, and the ambiguation problem would also be resolved.

Thus the solution will be as follows

```
Interface split
  Module Procedure split_to_int_unidim
  Module Procedure split_to_real_unidim
End Interface split

Function split_to_int_unidim (a, delim, b1, pos) Result (b)
  Character(len=*), Intent (in) :: a, delim
  Character(len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: pos
  Integer, Intent(out) :: b1
  Integer, Allocatable :: b(:)

  ...

  b1 = b(1)

End Function

Function split_to_real_unidim (a, delim, b1, pos) Result (b)
  Character(len=*), Intent (in) :: a, delim
  Character(len=*), Intent (in), Optional :: pos
  Real, Intent(out) :: b1
  Real, Allocatable :: b(:)

  ...

  b1 = b(1)

End Function
```

Comment: In that case make it a subroutine.

Comment: To fill one data type information, I rather use a function. If I want to split them using different variable names, I have a `subroutine split (a,delim,b1,b2,b3,pos)`.

Comment: It is your design choice, but it is not the usual one. See how they did it for `transfer` intrinsic, they did not include any bogus output argument, but a dummy input in which only the type is important.

Comment: Personally, I would just use the specific functions.

Comment: That's interesting point. What you mean exactly by: use the specific functions.

Comment: By that I mean forget the generics in this case. That, or use a dummy distinguishing argument, but just a dummy one, not output.

Comment: How would your suggestion taken from `transfer` be replicated to my functions.

Comment: You would add one argument `yyy, intent(in) :: mold`.

Comment: I suggest to have generic as I have other routines for other types (strings, int, and real) that output arrays. Then for each one I have subroutines that ouput to different arguments such as `subroutine split_to_int (a,delim,i1,i2,i3,pos)`. And again for strings and reals.

Comment: What is the `yyy` about?

Comment: yyy is your function result type.

Comment: Got it. Have just changed variable to be `intent(in)` rather than `out`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64799/discussion-between-christopher-dimech-and-vladimir-f).